# Display lines present in latest date and not in earlier date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new in power bi . I have a column name extract and a column name cle. I use extract as a filter segment where i can select 2 date. I want to display in a table the key present in the latest date and not present in the earlier date of my selection.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPjdD.png)

For example:

If I select in my filter date 14/04/2023 and date 28/04/2023 , it should display only cle "KB150"

If I select date 14/04/2023 and date 21/05/2023 , it should display only key "KB200"

If I select date 14/04/2023 and date 21/04/2023 , it should be blank
Thanks you for your help

Comment: How you will select 2 dates? In 2 different Filter?

Comment: I use a filter with date values where i can do multiples selections

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure:

```
Measure = 
VAR M=MAX('Table'[Extract])
RETURN 
CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Cle]),'Table'[Extract]=M)
```

> Your example 1:

[image]

> Your example 2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. Can you please show me your pbix because i created the same measure and it displays nothing.

Comment: how can send you pbix file, your email address?

Comment: relaxandal@gmail.com

Comment: sure if works please help accept this answer. (buttons in the left of my answer)

Comment: it's not working for all the cases. I put a new comment with picture

Comment: "When i choose 28/04/2023 and 28/05/2023, it should be blank because it's the same cle"   followed by your rule mentioned before, it should be the cle of 28/05/2023.  You want it to be blank then it should be another rule. This measure indeed cannot do for two rules.

Comment: I want to display the cle present in the lastest date and not in the earlier date

Comment: Yes that's the first rule you mentioned in your question description. i think the measure handles. but you mentioned in answer is another rule different with the first one. so two rules.

Comment: would like to suggest you edit your question description to include these two rules so that others may can help you.

Comment: No worries. Glad that can help you for a little bit.